# checkboxes default checked greyed out

Tags: html, checkbox

Is there a way in html markup to have a checkbox greyed-out and checked?

I wan't to keep the checkbox styled depending on the browser, so not alter it too much with css.

I'm trying to have a row of 4 checkboxes. One is checked and blue by default, the other three are disabled and greyed out. When you either: 
- click on the first one the other three become actively blue again 
- or when you click on one of the three disabled ones the first one becomes inactive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked onclick="return false"/>
```

OR

```
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled />
```

The `disabled` will gray it out, the first example won't

Answer (score 0):

Add `disabled="disabled"` to the end of the input tag. If you wanted the checkbox to be ticked on load add `checked` instead.